# Chrome does not fire `mouseup` under certain circumstances

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, mouseup

I had a simple solution for detecting if mouse button is pressed or not:

```
$('body').mousedown(function() {
  isMouseDown = true;
})
.on('mouseup dragend', function() {
  isMouseDown = false;
})
```

and it worked until recently it stopped since Chrome 46. The circumstances are rather complicated. [Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6tvxzq30/1/) Try to "select" the cells with your mouse. In Chrome 46+ and browsers based on it, when you release your mouse button the cells keep being selected on mouse enter. In other browsers, no such problem.

This is probably due to the fact that the cells are being replacedWith with jQuery instead of just adding some class to them. But in my case this is absolutely necessary.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to check if mouse button is pressed or not without errors.

Comment: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6tvxzq30/1/ although I'm not sure you're being terribly clear.

Comment: I have some sort of a grid of square blocks, like in the fiddle. When you press the block, it is being replaced with another block. You can replace multiple blocks this with a single gesture, like with a brush stroke.

Comment: That is what your fiddle does now. What do you want it to do?

Comment: It keeps selecting blocks when the mouse button is released

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93679/discussion-between-brad-evans-and-juribiyan).